# Bash: Echoing an argument after a slash inserts a blank character

Tags: bash

I'm trying to construct a path using a command-line argument in bash. I added the following line to my .bashrc:

```
alias hi="echo '/path/to/$1'"
```

However, this yields:

```
~$ hi foo
/path/to/ foo
```

Any idea where the blank after the slash is coming from?

Thanks

Hannes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, aliases can't take arguments. You can make a function instead:

```
 $ function hi() { echo "/path/to/$1"; }
 $ hi foo
 /path/to/foo
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/shell-script-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-an-unix-alias) for other options.

Answer (score 1):

As **Lukáš Lalinský** stated, aliases don't take arguments, so `$1` is null. However, even if you were to do this:

```
alias hi="echo '/path/to/'"
```

you'd get a space. The reason for this is so that if you had an alias like this:

```
alias myls=ls
```

and did:

```
myls filename
```

it wouldn't try to run:

```
lsfilename
```