# parameter subsitution in bash aliases

Tags: bash, unix

in tcsh we can create a alias for example

```
alias kate 'kate \!* &'
```

after this i can run a command on the shell like

```
kate test.py
```

which will be translated to

```
kate test.py &
```

what is the equivalent of this in bash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shell Script: How to pass command line arguments to an UNIX alias?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/shell-script-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-an-unix-alias)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash does have an `alias` feature but the Posix syntax (shared by bash, dash, ash, ksh, etc...) is all that is needed for this case so one may as well just do:

```
kate () {
  /usr/local/bin/kate "$@" &
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash you can create alias like this

```
alias myls='ls -l'
```

and after that if u type myls it will list the directories

Answer (score 0):

In bash a simple rsh illustrative  example to host passed through command line

```
function myrsh() {
    rsh $1.eng.testme.com -l mylogin
}
```

Now use `$> myrsh <hostname>`