# use commandline arguments in bash aliases

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, aliases

I am new to linux and trying to create an alias that starts mongodb service.
The original command is `sudo service mongod start`. I want to generalise this usage for any service.

i.e. something like `alias startservice="echo <password> | sudo -S $1 start"`.

So I would call it like `startservice mongod` should run the first command. I came to know that I can use functions for the same. However, I don't have a clue on how to do this either way.

Because I want my function which I create to be able to be accessible across terminals. I am not sure on how to create functions that act in this manner. Please help me on this.

I have gone through these two links:

[parameter subsitution in bash aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644653/parameter-subsitution-in-bash-aliases)

[Alias with Argument in Bash - Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867863/alias-with-argument-in-bash-mac)

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to do a function, not an alias

Comment: @Arount I understand that, however, I am not sure how to add a global function. that is what I want to know about. Thanks

Comment: Just create a file, like `~/.custom_functions` with your functions and at the end of your `~/.bashrc` add this line: `source ~/.custom_functions` so your functions will be "loaded" when you login to your account and will be ready to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Example of function in `bash`:

```
startService(){
  echo "your-password" | sudo -S service "$1" start
}

startService mongod                                    # test
```