# How can I expand arguments to a bash function into a chain of piped commands?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I often find myself doing something like this a lot:

```
something | grep cat | grep bat | grep rat
```

when all I recall is that those three words must have occurred somewhere, in some order, in the output of `something`...Now, i could do something like this:

```
something | grep '.*cat.*bat.*rat.*'
```

but that implies ordering (bat appears after cat). As such, I was thinking of adding a bash function to my environment called `mgrep` which would turn:

```
mgrep cat bat rat
```

into

```
grep cat | grep bat | grep rat
```

but I'm not quite sure how to do it (or whether there is an alternative?). One idea would be to for loop over the parameters like so:

```
while (($#)); do
    grep $1 some_thing > some_thing
    shift
done
cat some_thing
```

where some_thing is possibly some fifo like when one does `>(cmd)` in bash but I'm not sure. How would one proceed?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/shell-script-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-an-unix-alias

Comment: Generate the whole pipeline as a string, and execute it with `eval`

Comment: Yes i was thinking of a bash function, and thanks alexis that's a good idea lemme try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you *could* generate a pipeline one command at a time, by redirecting stdin at each step. But it's much simpler and cleaner to generate your pipeline as a string and execute it with eval, like this:

```
CMD="grep '$1' "  # consume the first argument
shift

for arg in "$@"   # Add the rest in a pipeline
do
  CMD="$CMD | grep '$arg'"
done
eval $CMD
```

This will generate a pipeline of greps that always reads from standard input, as in your model. Note that it protects spaces in quoted arguments, so that it works correctly if you write:

```
mgrep 'the cat' 'the bat' 'the rat'
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Alexis, this is what I did:

```
function mgrep() #grep multiple keywords
{
    CMD=''
    while (($#)); do
        CMD="$CMD grep \"$1\" | "
        shift
    done
    eval ${CMD%| }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the `${X%}` syntax. But think about quoting `$1` like I did-- sooner or later you'll want to include a shell metacharacter in your search, or to search for a phrase, and your function will break. And it's just better to write robust code when it's so easy!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a recursive function; I'm not happy with the base case, but I can't think of a better one. It seems a waste to need to call `cat` just to pass standard input to standard output, and the while loop is a bit inelegant:

```
mgrep () {
    local e=$1;
    # shift && grep "$e" | mgrep "$@" || while read -r; do echo "$REPLY"; done
    shift && grep "$e" | mgrep "$@" || cat

    # Maybe?
    # shift && grep "$e" | mgrep "$@" || echo "$(</dev/stdin)"
}
```

Comment: I like this! Clever. How/why does it terminate though?

Comment: Ah, good question. `shift` has a nonzero exit if its implied argument of 1 is greater than the number of positional arguments. In that case, `cat` is called instead of the recursive `grep`/`mgrep` pipeline.