# Command string mangling fun

Tags: bash

Consider the following command block:

```
if [[ ${EXTRA_PROCESS} -eq 1 ]]; then
  producer | tee >(calc1 > ${out1}) >(calc2 > ${out2}) | consumer
else
  producer | tee >(calc1 > ${out1}) | consumer
fi
```

This does what it's supposed to do. However, that's rather a lot of code repartition. So I changed it to look like this:

```
TEE="tee >(calc1 > ${out1})"
if [[ ${EXTRA_PROCESS} -eq 1 ]]; then
  TEE="$TEE >(calc2 > ${out2})"
fi
producer | ${TEE} | consumer
```

That's much less code duplication. Unfortunately, the script is now completely broken. When I run it, it creates three giant files in the current directory:

```
blackbox:~ # ls
>
>(calc1
>(calc2
...
```

(I'm impressed that it's even *possible* to have files with those names in the first place... Deleting them was even more fun!)

Can somebody explain

- Why Bash is treating the strings literally rather than interpreting them?
- How I can force Bash to actually do what I asked for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I expand arguments to a bash function into a chain of piped commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334429/how-can-i-expand-arguments-to-a-bash-function-into-a-chain-of-piped-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
if [[ ${EXTRA_PROCESS} -eq 1 ]]; then
  function Tee()
  {
    tee >(calc1 > ${out1}) >(calc2 > ${out2})
  }
else
  function Tee()
  {
    tee >(calc1 > ${out1})
  }
fi

producer | Tee | consumer
```

For the example actually shown, this is quite a bit more typing. *However*, when you have multiple independent on/off options, doing it this way prevents a combinatorial explosion of slightly different pipelines.

```
producer | Option1 | Option2 | Option3 | consumer
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why Bash is treating the strings literally rather than interpreting
>   them?

When you store the redirection operators in strings, those tend to lose their *special* meaning.  This is the reason that you're able to have filenames like `>(calc1`.

> How I can force Bash to actually do what I asked for?

I'd suggest sticking to the way you've done it in your first code block.  It might appear to duplicate code but an alternative (see below) isn't really recommended.

---

Alternate ([`not recommended`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)):

```
eval "producer | ${TEE} | consumer"
```

---

A better alternative would be to use functions:

```
foo1() {
  producer | tee >(calc1 > ${out1}) >(calc2 > ${out2}) | consumer;
}

foo2() {
  producer | tee >(calc1 > ${out1}) | consumer;
}

if [[ ${EXTRA_PROCESS} -eq 1 ]]; then
  foo1
else
  foo2
fi
```

Comment: The real script has _multiple_ settable options, resulting in a combinatorial explosion of nearly identical but subtly different commands in a deeply-nested if-block... I'd really like something that humans can actually read and understand.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Not much can be said without looking at the script, but for the example you've mentioned consider using functions.

Comment: Wrapping each duplicate copy of the pipeline in a function doesn't really do anything about the actual duplication... unless there's some way to use a function as just one part of a pipeline? Because with 4 on/off options, that's 2^4 = 16 nearly identical pipelines I need to edit (_and test!_)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Does that leave you with `eval`?