# Function instead of alias in C shell login script

Tags: shell, authentication, alias

I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/shell-script-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-an-unix-alias) topic that you can add a function in the shell login script instead of an alias if you want to use parameters. However, I placed the following code inside my .cshrc file in the section with aliasses:

```
function gf()
{
    grep -n $1 `find .` | grep -v "can't open"
}
```

But when I type source .cshrc, I get the error message: Badly placed ()'s. Is the syntax different for a C shell than in a Bash shell? If so, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't define functions in `csh`, like you can in most other shells. This feature does not exist in `csh`.

The only alternative is to create a script and place it in a directory on your `PATH` e.g. `~/bin`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, that does not help, I still get the same error in that case.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Functions are not supported in `csh`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for passing only one argument, just put `\!$` where you wish your argument to sit.

For example:

If you put `alias mygrep grep -i \!$ myfile.txt` in `~/.cshrc`, and run `mygrep mykeyword`, `csh` will run `alias mygrep grep -i mykeyword myfile.txt`.

See [this](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch29_03.htm) for more info.

Comment: This should be the answer. Also from your link: `\!:n` gets you the `n`th argument

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
#!/bin/csh

if ("$1" == "run") goto $2

echo "Now in default mode"

echo "Calling myself"

csh -f dummy run sub1

csh -f dummy run sub2

exit


sub1:

echo "In sub1"

exit

sub2:

echo "In sub2"

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the following in your `.cshrc` or `.tcshrc`:

```
alias function '( set argv = ( \!* ) ; source ~/.cshfuncs )'
```

Define your functions in `.cshfuncs`:

```
# Functions for C Shell.

switch ("$1")
  case "myfunc":
    grep -n "$2" "`find .`" | grep -v "can't open"
    exit
  case "myfunc2":
    echo "Another function."
    exit
  default:
    echo "Function $1 not set."
    exit -1
endsw
```