# How to alias emacs --eval "(ediff...)" in c-shell

Tags: shell, alias, csh

I was looking for a way to alias the emacs ediff for easier use in c-shell.
When writing `emacs --eval "(ediff "f1" "f2")"`, emacs is opened in ediff mode, comparing file f1 to file f2.
When trying to alias it, however, I didn't find a way to insert the files names from the command line.
The following code works for bash, but not for c-shell (because [c-shell don't support functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916515/function-instead-of-alias-in-c-shell-login-script)):

```
function ediff() {  
    emacs --eval "(ediff \"$1\" \"$2\")"}
```

Also tried `emacs --eval "(ediff \!*)"`, but it didn't work as well.
Anyone knows of a way to make this aliasing?

*edit*
Following the suggestion in the comments, I created a bash script called ediff that all it does is `emacs --eval "(ediff \"$1\" \"$2\")"`.
Couldn't make the csh to even eval *\"$1\"*!

Comment: I removed tags `emacs` and `eval`. The question is not about Emacs or `ediff`. It is about shell command aliasing.

Comment: in csh, the best you can do is make it into a callable script. Then you can pass in a whole cmd-line full of arguments. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - it is a valid possibility, but id there is a solution, I'd rather find it.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes, but break out of them for arguments like !:1. Also escape double quotes, !, spaces, and parentheses with \.

The result is:

```
alias ediff emacsclient --eval '\(ediff-files\ \"'\!:1'\"\ \"'\!:2'\"\)'
```