# How to define 'alias' in csh

Tags: linux, shell, csh, tcsh

I meet an issue:
I want to define a `alias` in `.cshrc.user`: `alias lsco 'ct lsco -me -avobs -cview | awk '{print $5}''`.

But this is not work for me, and this is an error `Missing }.` when run `source .cshrc.user`.

The shell in my computer is `/bin/tcsh`.

Comment: there is command called `man`,  E.g. `man ls` , `man grep`... in your case, it should be `man alias`

Comment: @Kent Since when shell builtins have a man page? In this case it should be `man csh`.. But try it! I spent my last 15 minutes to figure out how to escape the `$` :)

Comment: @hek2mgl the question was tagged with linux + shell, and I spotted the missing `=` in alias statement.  didn't notice the `tcsh`, my bad. I don't have experience with `tcsh`. if commands are getting complicated, a function could be considered too.

Comment: @Kent Probably a function is the way to go here. Good point.

Comment: @hek2mgl read has a man page...

Comment: @Kent Looks like [you can't define functions in csh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13916548/171318) ..

Comment: @123 That's not the man page of the shell builtin `read`, it's the man page of the glibc function `read()`. How to retrieve help for a shell builtin depends on the shell. In bash you can type `help read`.

Comment: @hek2mgl cd has a man page.

Comment: @123 aren't you just listing commands that have an implementation in coreutils as well as in some shells?

Comment: @TomFenech yes i am.

Comment: @hek2mgl thx for the info.... now I feel lucky that I don't have to work with tsch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
alias lsco 'ct lsco -me -avobs -cview | awk "{print "\$"5}"'
```

Comment: I've seen it written like `"\$5"` too [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/tcsh-escaping-'-or-$-377216/) but I guess it doesn't matter whether the number is inside or outside the quotes.

Comment: @TomFenech Yes, it doesn't matter. It was my first time playing around with `csh`. I need to say that I'm not satisfied with the feature set.