# Linux Alias, what's wrong with it?

Tags: linux, alias

I've got this alias:

```
alias gi='grep -r -i $1 ./*'
```

when i do

```
gi someString
```

It does the grep, but on some other string than that which I provide, usually with a "p/ or other such thing in it.

I'm using something similar for grepping history:

```
alias gh='history | grep $1'
```

Which works perfectly.

EDIT:  I am on the /bin/bash shell, as per echo $SHELL.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably share which shell you're using as well.

Comment: *alias* is just your particular shell built-in command. The *shell* you are using is probably *bash*. It doesn't actually matter, because *alias* is Posix and the answer applies to any Posix shell.

Comment: Sorry Digi, not sure what confusion you're addressing in this comment?  Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alias` mechanism merely substitutes for a word. Any *other* words on the same line are left in place, so typically one just replaces the command and leaves the arguments. This doesn't work well for your *grep* example because you want to rearrange the line.

Now, `$1` will refer to the shell process (or shell function) parameters, in either case, *not* to words typed on the same line.

You would be better served in this case with a shell *function*, which should work on any Posix shell including bash.

```
gi () {
  grep -r -i "$1" ./*
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass arguments to `alias` , please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/shell-script-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-an-unix-alias) for details. What you need is a function. Try something on the lines:

```
function gi() {
grep -r -i "$1" ./*
}
```

Hope this helps!

P.S.: As to why `alias gh='history | grep $1'` works is because it is the same as `alias gh='history | grep`. `$1` is expanded when set an `alias` statically.

Comment: Thanks for that link.  Up voted, but Dig beat you to the punch on the actual answer ;-)

Comment: @Nathaniel: Not a problem, his answer actually explains a lot more :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this alias:

```
alias gi='find . | xargs grep -i'
```

If you still just want to use alias to solve your problem, this will work.