# Create Laravel5 app using bash function passing in app name as argument

Tags: bash, function, shell, composer-php, laravel-5

I want to create a bash shell function to create a new laravel 5 project by passing in the app name as an argument.

This is what I have so far:

```
function new {
    composer create-project laravel/laravel $1 dev-develop --prefer-dist
}
```

I call it by `new project-name`

However I get this error:

**[UnexpectedValueException]
  Could not parse version constraint hawksmoorcs: Invalid version string "project-name"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by following [Thomas Bratts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15985/thomas-bratt)'s answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/shell-script-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-unix-alias?rq=1) question.

```
alias new='function _create_new_laravel_5_project(){ composer create-project laravel/laravel "$1" dev-develop --prefer-dist; echo "created project $1";};_create_new_laravel_5_project'
```

You can call it using `new name-of-laravel-5-project`

**Perfect!**