# Unix Bash Alias Command

Tags: bash, unix, alias

I am trying to simplify my work with the help of Alias commands in my bash shell.

**Problem Statement:**
I want to copy different files from different directories to one single folder. The syntax i am using here is as below

```
cp <folder>/<file>    <path>/file.dir
```

Here I want to save the destination file with filename.directory for easy identification. To achieve the same, I have written the below alias.

**Alias Script**

```
cp $Folder/$fileName ~/<path>/$fileName.$Folder
```

**OR**

```
cp $1/$2 ~/<path>/$2.$1
```

**Expected output,**

1. `cp bin/file1 ~/Desktop/personal/file1.bin`
2. `cp etc/file2 ~/Desktop/personal/file2.etc*`

However, It's failing at parsing the source file. i.e. `$Folder` is not replaced with my first argument.

```
cp: cannot stat `/file1': No such file or directory
```

I am writing the above script only to reduce my command lengths. As I am not expert in the above code, seeking any expert help in resolving the issue.

Comment: From `man bash` under **ALIASES**, "There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used (see FUNCTIONS below)."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make bash alias that takes parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter)

Comment: Maybe use csh instead of bash so you can do this the way you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/shell-script-how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-unix-alias

Comment: @sndsnd: As someone who switched *from* csh *to* bash, I would not recommend this. Bash, unlike, csh, has functions, and they're much more powerful than aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an alias you could use a function which you define in some suitable location such as .profile or .bashrc

For example:

```
mycp()
{
   folder=$1
   filename=$2

   if [ $# -ne 2 ]
   then
       echo "Two parameters not entered"
       return
   fi

   if  [ -d $folder -a -r $folder/$filename ]
   then
      cp $folder/$filename ~/playpen/$filename.$folder
   else
      echo "Invalid parameter"
   fi
}
```

Comment: You should double-quote the `$variable` like `"$variable"` to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way a bash `alias` can use arguments as you are trying to do. However, perl based [`rename`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=rename) can probably help you here. Note that it will effectively `mv` the files, not `cp` them.

```
rename 's|([^/]*)/(.*)|/home/user/path/$2.$1|' */*
```

Limitations: You can only process the files in 1 sub-directory level.

So, below alias can work (with above limitation):

```
$ alias backupfiles="rename 's|([^/]*)/(.*)|/home/user/path/\$2.\$1|'"
$ backupfiles */*
```

You can make more sophisticated perl expression if you want to work with multi-directory-level file structure.

Answer (score 0):

A directory contains some files say ~/Documents/file1.d contains newfile.txt

```
joe@indiana:~/Documents$ ls -l $file
total 1
-rw-r--r--   1 joe      staff          0 May  5 11:39 newfile.txt
```

Add the variable 'file' in .bashrc for example my .bashrc is shown here

```
alias ll='ls -la'
file=~/Documents/file1.d
```

Now whenever you copy to '$file' it will copy to file1.d directory under ~/Documents :)