# Need help creating an alias in korn shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, alias

I am stuck on trying to create an alias that will cd back a directory, make a new directory with a given name and then cd into it. Here is what I have so far:

alias cdmk="cd .. | mkdir '$1' | cd '$1'"

I just want to be able to type cdmk and then the name of the new directory I want to create and cd into.

Any help you can give would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use a function.  This has been answered [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-shell-alia](here).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a function:

```
cdmk() {
    local new_dir="../$1"
    mkdir "$new_dir" && cd "$new_dir"
}
```

Using `&&` means that if creating the directory fails, changing to it is not attempted.

Comment: Thank you!
Can I enter this straight into my .profile?

Comment: You have my express permission `;-)`

Comment: Seems to come up with "Syntax error: `(' is not expected." when I try and run it... Any idea why?

Comment: Sounds like an error possibly related to line endings - you need to make sure that your `.profile` has the correct line endings for the platform you're using (i.e. not Windows-style ones).

Comment: @Jack, how did you _try and run it_?

Answer (score 0):

You need a function :

```
cdmk () { cd ..;mkdir "${1}";cd "${1}"; }
```

Comment: When I enter this into my .profile and touch it, it comes up with "Syntax error: `(' is not expected". Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: @Jack, what do you mean by _touch it_?