# bash script to run lftp with ftp path

Tags: bash, sed, .profile

I'm trying to write a bash alias/function that takes an ftp path and runs `lftp` to `pget` the file.

Given a remote path, with spaces encoded as `%20` like:

`sftp://ftp.example.com/Some%20Folder/BigFile.mov`

I have this snippet to clean up the `%20` and server part of the URL:

`echo $1 | sed 's/%20/ /g' | sed 's/sftp:\/\/ftp.example.com//g';`

which gives me

`/Some Folder/BigFile.mov`

Now I need to run this through `lftp` like this:

`lftp sftp://ftp.example.com -u user,pass -e "pget -cn10 '/Some Folder/BigFile.mov'"`

I want to create an alias with a function to this command, let's call it `lget`, so I can just use the original URL:

`lget "sftp://ftp.example.com/Some%20Folder/BigFile.mov"`

The solution here should like something like

```
alias lget='function _lget(){ lftp ... };_lget'
```

But I get completely lost as to how to include the argument in the function, have it processed through `sed`, and how to handle the nested quotation marks.

I probably need some backticks ...

Comment: Use a function instead of an alias and the rest should come easily.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a lot of bash scripting knowledge; how would you write the function to include the processed URL within the `lftp` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
lget () {
    local filename=${1#sftp://ftp.example.com}
    lftp sftp://ftp.example.com -u user,pass -e "pget -cn10 '${filename//%20/ }'"
}
```

I don't see why you would want to create a function with a useless name only to be able to assign the useful name to an alias which simply calls the function (though this seems to be the norm in some circles, for reasons unknown to me).

You don't need `sed` because Bash contains built-in functions for string substitution. If you need this to be portable to POSIX shell, which lacks the `${variable//global/replacement}` functionality (and the `local` keyword), take care to [properly quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable/27701642#27701642) the string you pass to `sed`.  (The `${variable#prefix}` syntax to retrieve the value of a variable with a prefix removed is available in POSIX shell. Oh, and for the record, a single `sed` script can perform multiple substitutions; `sed -e 's/foo/bar/' -e 's/baz/quux/g'`.)

Comment: Brilliant! It works! I only mentioned the function within an alias because I saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-shell-alias ; Didn't realize the function was enough by itself. Thanks!

Comment: One more question ... can that function be written in one line? Line breaks are significant in bash, right?

Comment: Line breaks can be replaced with a semicolon.  You don't need one after the opening brace. Unclear to me why you would have such a requirement, though.

Comment: I eventually asked [Why would I create an alias which creates a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57239089/why-would-i-create-an-alias-which-creates-a-function) and got some speculative answers.