# Windows Git Bash Whitespace Alias Issue

Tags: windows, git, bash, visual-studio, shell

This might be an issue with Git Bash for Windows.

I am trying to create an alias with parameters to enter some workspace to the specific project directories. However, it seems to have some whitespace issues for Visual Studio Project directories. I tried to double quote the variable, but the error output is rather ambiguous because copying the the cd output works on the bash window.

```
VS="/c/Users/name/Documents/Visual\ Studio\ 2015/Projects"
alias wkp='function _b(){ cd "'${VS}'"/$1; };_b'
```

It outputs

```
bash: cd: /c/Users/name/Documents/Visual\ Studio\ 2015/Projects/: No such file or directory
```

Working on a regular alias it will be fine, but I will need to cd again into the specific project directory.

```
alias workp='cd /c/Users/name/Documents/Visual\ Studio\ 2015/Projects'
```

Is there a reason why whitespaces with backslash and double quote in the parameter won't work for bash functions?

Previous relevant questions
[Make a Bash alias that takes a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-bash-alias-that-takes-parameter)
[How to pass command line arguments to a shell alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-shell-alias)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. I needed to remove the backslash in this case.

```
VS="/c/Users/name/Documents/Visual\ Studio\ 2015/Projects"

VS="/c/Users/name/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects"
```

It seems cd will take the double quote completely and parse whitespace without needing to use the backslash as an escape.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use:

```
alias devenv=\""/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/devenv.exe\""
```

or else I got

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```