# How to pass argument to alias/function in bash and fish at once

Tags: bash, shell, fish

My question is very similar to: [How to pass command line arguments to a shell alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-shell-alias)

I want to create alias that will accept arguments. Guys in above question suggested functions and indeed this is solution.

However, I am using at once fish (Friendly Interactive SHell) and bash. I keep all my custom aliases in single file, that I load no matter if I am using fish or bash.

I know how to create alias/functions in bash, and I know how to create alias/functions in fish. I do not know, how to create alias/function at once for both fish and bash.

It doesn't have to be alias/function (it can be edgy hack), just end effect should work like expected.

alias rmi="function _rmi() { docker ps -a | grep $1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm -f ; docker images | grep $1 | awk '{print $3}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi -f }; _rmi()"

Above one is accepted by bash, but not fish.

function go
        sudo service $argv restart
end

Above is accepted by fish, but now bash.

alias apts="aptitude search"

Plain aliases as above one are accepted by both bash and fish, but argument cannot be inside (must be at very end).

How to unify it?

Comment: If you are trying to remove images look at `docker system prune --help`. This command is better at what you are doing with aliases. Not related to question you asked but might help build a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no proper general solution to this, fish is not compatible with bash.

Also, the `alias something="function"` is unnecessary. You can just define the function directly.

If what you wish to execute does not change anything about the shell's internal state, you can make a script instead.

E.g. create a file called "rmi" that contains

```
#!/bin/bash
docker ps -a | grep $1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm -f
docker images | grep $1 | awk '{print $3}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi -f
```

somewhere in $PATH (in both bash and fish).

Comment: I can create aliases, that would invoke those scripts, so this IS general solution!