# Set up bash alias with command line argument and wildcard

Tags: bash

I am not familiar with bash, but I would like to make an alias that deletes all files starting with a certain string. Here's what I have in my `.bashrc`:

```
alias myrm="rm $1*"
```

but that does not seem to work properly... What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass command line arguments to a shell alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-shell-alias)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases can't use arguments. Use a function instead:

```
myrm() { rm "$1"*; }
```

Quoting [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html):

> There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text, as in csh. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used.

Comment: @Hilbert It's most likely because the `alias` is still defined. Try to `unalias` it before `sourcing` the `.bashrc`.