# Ubuntu how to create a shortcut that execute a command

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command-line

When I work I often do:

```
cd ~/dev/lab/prod/
```

It is just an example but I would like to be able just to run:

```
prod
```

With the same effect (changing into the ~/dev/lab/prod folder).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass command line arguments to a shell alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-shell-alias)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Alias**](http://www.linfo.org/alias.html) is what you are looking for.

For **bash** you have to do following steps:

1) Open your `.bashrc`

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

2) Add new alias (at the end of file)

```
alias prod='cd ~/dev/lab/prod/'
```

3) Save and close the file

4) Source the `.bashrc` file

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

5) Use created alias `prod` for `cd ~/dev/lab/prod/` command

Comment: Thanks, I most edit ./zshrc instead ./bashrc, it is exactly what I needed

Answer (score -1):

1. Open a text editor
2. Name the file prod.sh
3. Add the following line:

   ```
   cd ~/dev/lab/prod
   ```
4. Make the file script executable:

   ```
   chmod +x prod.sh
   ```
5. Run the file

   ```
   ./prod.sh
   ```

Comment: This is broken, and a common FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-shell-script