# Bash alias function for copying multiple files using SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line-interface, alias

I want to copy multiple files from one server to another and I have to do it using scp from server to local then local to the server.

I created an alias function for the same using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-shell-alias)

```
alias copy_file='function _copy(){ scp tarun@server1.com:/path_to_folder/"$1" ./ && scp "$1" tarun@server2.com:/path_to_folder/ ; };_copy'
```

It works for single file like this

`copy_file temp1`

But when I try to copy multiple files like this explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327282/copying-multiple-specific-files-from-one-folder-to-another)

`copy_file {temp1,temp2}`

It only copies the first file

However, when I run the alias command directly it copies both the file. Like this:

```
scp tarun@server1.com:/path_to_folder/{temp1,temp2} ./ && scp {temp1,temp2} tarun@server2.com:/path_to_folder/
```

Please help.

Comment: When sending `{temp1,temp2}`, `temp2` is handled as second argument, `$2`.

Comment: @samthegolden thanks for the info but I don't have a fixed number of files to copy

Comment: @tarunjain : The title of your posting is confusing. Are you looking for an alias or for a function? There is no _alias function_. What you posted, is just an alias which, when executed, creates a function and invokes it afterwards (which is a somewhat odd usage of an alias).

Comment: Yeah, so I want a bash function alias for handy use as I have to copy some files from one server to another now and then... Please suggest an alternative solution to this or suggest a different title if it's confusing.

Comment: @tarunjain check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Pass function argument in double quote:

```
copy_file "{temp1,temp2}"
```

otherwise, bash will parse these as separate function input which `$1` will be temp1 and `$2` will be temp2

**EDIT**

second scp command will see "{temp1,temp2}" as a filename. scp syntax need separate file name so we will separate these file names with following function:

```
scp tarun@server1.com:/path_to_folder/"$1" ./ && tmp="$1" && tmp=${tmp#"{"} && tmp=${tmp%"}"} && IFS=',' && array="$tmp" && scp $array tarun@server2.com:/path_to_folder/
```

Comment: Thanks @mjrezaee, It copied both the files on local but it says {temp1,temp2}: No such file or directory while copying it to the server again

Comment: There is ```$@``` variable for all the variables if that could help, but I am not able to get around that.

Comment: @tarunjain i edited my answer to work with one-liner function and minimum scp command usage, i hope this works.

Comment: Can you please explain how are you taking care of all the arguments passed in the alias function?

Comment: @tarunjain copying multiple file through `scp` can be done by using space separated file names like `scp temp1 temp2 tarun@server2.com:/path_to_folder/`. So i removed `{' and `}` from input argument string (becomes `temp1,temp2`) and then i split this new string by `,` separator into an array (becomes `[temp1 temp2]`) 

final alias will be:
`alias copy_file='function _copy(){ scp tarun@server1.com:/path_to_folder/"$1" ./ && tmp="$1" && tmp=${tmp#"{"} && tmp=${tmp%"}"} && IFS=',' && array="$tmp" && scp $array tarun@server2.com:/path_to_folder/ ;}; _copy'`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the files with `$@`, which represents the number of input arguments:

`alias copy_file='function _copy(){ for file in "$@"; do scp tarun@server1.com:/path_to_folder/"$file" ./ && scp "$file" tarun@server2.com:/path_to_folder/ ; done;};_copy'`

This way your alias is prepared to deal with undefined number of files.

This will, however, run multiple `scp` commands instead of a single one.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Will use this for now but why the other syntax is not working?? Is there any strict rule of typing in terminal commands.

Comment: I think it's because you can set a list of files to copy from, but you can't set a list of file locations to copy to.

Comment: I am actually looking for a single line answer and the problem with my solution.