# How to pass pod name in alias of kubectl exec command?

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I am trying to connect with kubernetes pod and tail logs using the alias

```
# Alias
alias logs=kubectl exec -it -n namespace "$@" -- tail -f /var/log/containers/app.log
```

Now when I use alias and pass actual pod name to which I want to connect it doesn't work.

logs pod-name

Please help to resolve this.

Comment: try to add single quotes:
`alias logs='kubectl exec -it -n namespace "$@" -- tail -f /var/log/containers/app.log'`

Comment: But it looks like you want to add an argument to an alias. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-shell-alias

Comment: Yes I want to pass actual pod name with the alias, but it seems "$@" is not taking that podname agrument..

Comment: Can you change your application or its configuration so that it logs to stdout instead of a file?  Then you could just run `kubectl logs -n namespace containername`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
function logs { kubectl exec -it "$1" -n namespace "$2" -- tail -f /var/log/containers/app.log }
export -f logs
```

Then you an use as

```
logs podName nameSpace
```

Comment: Can you rewrite the function using standard, non-bash-specific Bourne shell syntax; `logs() { ... }`, without the non-standard `function` keyword or the `export -f` line?